# How many Gs are my clothes experiencing in my washer?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, centrifugal-force, estimation

During a spin cycle I got curious: How many Gs are at play in my simple washing machine?

We can assume the drum is 50 cm wide and spins at 1500 rpm.

Comment: Please look up 'centripetal acceleration' and calculate it. The divide by $g$ to find your number.

Comment: related:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D8ljH5uuHfA

Comment: @wim [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dq6T5BojXc8) is the higher resolution original.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The simplest formula for the centrifugal acceleration is
$$ a = r\omega^2 $$
Here, $r$ is the radius which is 0.25 meters in your case. $\omega$ is the angular velocity which is $2\pi$ times the frequency $f$. Your $f$ is 1500 revolutions per minute which is $1500/60=25$ revolutions per second.

In the SI units, we have
$$ a = 0.25\times 4\pi^2 \times 25^2 = 625\pi^2 $$
Because $\pi^2\sim 10$ is numerically close to $g\approx 9.81\,{\rm m}/{\rm s}^2$, you see that the clothes experience almost $600 g$. However, most of the clothes sits at a lower radius than 0.25 meters (distance from the rotation axis) so their acceleration is reduced proportionally to that.

I guess that most people are surprised how large the acceleration is; I was surprised. But it's needed to get most of the water from the clothes. The force holding the water inside the clothes is basically surface tension which microscopically boils down to electromagnetism. Electromagnetism is much stronger than gravity – and even the whole Earth's gravitational acceleration $1g$ is easily beaten by many forces caused by electromagnetism. In this case, we see that one needs something like $600g$ to "really beat" the surface tension. That's another way of saying that the gravity-caused $g$ is really small relatively to the accelerations produced by electromagnetic forces inside the matter.

Comment: Oddly I can't find any surface in the universe within an order of magnitude of 600g. There's a gap between [28g](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_gravity#Relationship_of_surface_gravity_to_mass_and_radius) on the Sun and [440,000g](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-gravity-of-a-white-dwarf) on a white dwarf. You know, to make this figure relatable and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Now, one g is equal to the acceleration due to gravity by Earth on its surface.
Force by washing machine is the centrifugal force as clothes try to go along straight path but the resultant provided by the walls of container of machine which provides the required centripetal force. Now, according to Newton's third law of motion , clothes will also give equal force which you are talking about.

Centrifugal acc. = (λ²)r
                { λ is angular velocity}

```
  ={1500×2π)/60}² × (50÷100)
```

=  6,168.5027 m/sec²
       =  600g ( in gs)

Comment: "50 cms wide" means a 25 cm radius. I have yet to see a domestic washer machine with 1 meter diameter drum. Yet you get to the same number than Lubos an hour before you... curious.

Comment: Lubos comparison is totally wrong with that of earth's gravitational force and that of small electromagnetic motor. U see  throw clothes or a military tank from my terrace gravity gives it same acceleration. This is because earth's gravitational pull is independent of mass of a body. But if puts the same military tank on your washing machine and we know the motor can produce a certain maximum torque.therefore,